# No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

Tags: java, android, webview

We are having a problem running our Android app built with IONIC framework run on Genymotion emulator, although it runs fine on a real hardware, a real android phone.

I can see an error thrown `No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp`

Here snippet of the complete log from logcat file:

```
09-27 21:53:24.258 I/ActivityManager( 5528): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.ionicframework.myappandroid393856/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0

09-27 21:53:24.317 I/art     ( 6438): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

09-27 21:53:24.318 I/ActivityManager( 5528): Start proc 6438:com.ionicframework.myappandroid393856/u0a60 for activity com.ionicframework.myappandroid393856/.MainActivity

09-27 21:53:24.375 W/System  ( 6438): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ionicframework.myappandroid393856-1/lib/x86

09-27 21:53:24.480 V/WebViewFactory( 6438): webViewPackageName: com.android.webview

09-27 21:53:24.482 I/WebViewFactory( 6438): Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)

09-27 21:53:24.514 W/System  ( 6438): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86

09-27 21:53:24.526 I/LibraryLoader( 6438): Time to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 8014-8015)

09-27 21:53:24.532 I/LibraryLoader( 6438): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""

09-27 21:53:24.577 V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider( 6438): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {10f7532}

09-27 21:53:24.578 I/LibraryLoader( 6438): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""

09-27 21:53:24.578 I/chromium( 6438): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0

09-27 21:53:24.589 I/BrowserStartupController( 6438): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true

09-27 21:53:24.589 W/art     ( 6438): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

09-27 21:53:24.590 E/SysUtils( 6438): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

09-27 21:53:24.659 W/chromium( 6438): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()

09-27 21:53:24.676 D/libEGL  ( 6438): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so

09-27 21:53:24.677 D/libEGL  ( 6438): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so

09-27 21:53:24.697 D/libEGL  ( 6438): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

09-27 21:53:24.704 E/libEGL  ( 6438): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

09-27 21:53:24.704 E/libEGL  ( 6438): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

09-27 21:53:24.705 D/        ( 6438): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8a614f0, tid 6438

09-27 21:53:24.881 E/eglCodecCommon( 6438): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008d57

09-27 21:53:25.010 W/AudioManagerAndroid( 6438): Requires BLUETOOTH permission

09-27 21:53:25.070 E/DataReductionProxySettingListener( 6438): No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

09-27 21:53:25.108 W/art     ( 6438): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

09-27 21:53:25.140 W/AwContents( 6438): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring

09-27 21:53:25.154 D/SystemWebViewEngine( 6438): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Genymotion

09-27 21:53:25.163 W/art     ( 6438): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

09-27 21:53:25.163 W/art     ( 6438): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

09-27 21:53:25.174 E/Surface ( 5893): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe8a03180

09-27 21:53:25.267 D/OpenGLRenderer( 6438): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

09-27 21:53:25.332 V/StatusBar( 6438): StatusBar: initialization
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue and it turned out to be the JavaScript that contained some ES6 fat arrows

> ()=> {...}

After removing them and returning to anonymous functions

> function () {...}

this error was no longer thrown on the Genymotion emulator.
It was still there on the Android Studio emulator but didn't affect the JavaScript execution.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for this propblem. I don't want to remove fat arrow functions.